# Confusion Matrix in Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

My confusion matrix created for a logistic regression model only has the values for Predicted-FALSE. Even though I adjusted my threshold, it does not do much to the matrix. What is wrong and how do I adjust the threshold? Below is the code for the training set and the result. "Retain" is my dependent variable with 1=retained 0=not retained, and all the independent variables are continuous variables. I have overall 170K records in the dataset (df). This matrix indicates that the model predicts that no one retained, which is odd, because in reality 45% retained.

```
model_1 <- glm(retain~ age_2010+cnt_total_funds+sum_MS_2010+tenure_2010, data=df, family="binomial")

res <- predict(model_1, training, retain="response")
(table(ActualValue=training$retain, PredictedValue=res>0.05))

PredictedValue
ActualValue FALSE
          0 96006
          1 43676
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake inside `predict` function as you want to use `type` argument (not `retain` which not exists for this function).
I use a sample data to show you working example.
In your example change `retain="response"` to `type="response"`.

```r
aa <- airquality
aa$retain <- aa$Ozone > 50
gg = glm(retain ~ Solar.R + Month, data = aa, family = "binomial")
range(predict(gg, aa, type = "response"), na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.05918388 0.48769632
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I am glad, then please accept the answer.

Comment: I am a newbie to Stack Overflow. How do I accept your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks that you remember. You should click the check mark under the voting arrows, for my answer.

Comment: Just did it. Thanks!